# What is the session size in Seam?

Tags: session, seam

I would like to know my session size in my application to optimize it.  To find this size, I use mat which does a heap dump and analyzes it.

Where does Seam store session and conversation beans?

I though it was in org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession but visibly no (I have only 2 octets in this bean).

Answer (score 0):

Seam stores everything in the HttpSession.

```
Name("someFilter")
@Filter(around = { "org.jboss.seam.web.ajax4jsfFilter" })
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
@Startup
@BypassInterceptors
public class SomeFilter extends AbstractFilter {

private static final LogProvider log = Logging.getLogProvider(SomeFilter.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (HttpServletRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(request.getClass())) {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
                if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
                    List<String> attrNames = Collections.list(session.getAttributeNames());
                    for (String o : attrNames) {
                        log.info("objects in session " + o);
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I found that too. Actually, mat has some problem to aquire directly a heap dump. If I use jmap, I found the good size.